# How to convert list of Objects to JSON in Spring MVC and Hibernate?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm Using Spring MVC and hibernate to fetch data from MySQL. In the controller class a ModelAndView method listEmployees is returning a MAP.The method is getting list of Employee objects from EmployeeService class. I want this method to take list of Employee Objects from Service class and covert it into JSON,or convert it into JSON and write that data in a JSON file so that I can use this JSON data in a JSP page.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
 public @ResponseBody ModelAndView listEmployees() {  
  Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  model.put("employees",prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));  
  return new ModelAndView("employeesList", model);  

 }

private List<EmployeeBean> prepareListofBean(List<Employee> employees){
        List<EmployeeBean> beans = null;
        if(employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()){
            beans = new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
            EmployeeBean bean = null;
            for(Employee employee : employees){
                bean = new EmployeeBean();
                bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
                bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
                bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
                bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
                bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
                beans.add(bean);
            }
        }
        return beans;
    }
```

**EDIT**

In this below method I tried GSON to convert list to JSON,but was getting null pointer Exception.

```
**@RequestMapping(value="/employees1", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public ModelAndView employeelist() {  

    Gson gson=new Gson();
    gson.toJson(employeeService.listEmployeess());

    ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject(gson);

    return modelAndView;

    }**
```

***What could be the mistake in this above method?***

Comment: `I can use this JSON data in a JSP page`, how you want to use it? Using ajax call?

Comment: There are many libraries built around this e.g. Jackson, GSON etc. Check those. Look for basic tutorials on them.
And try posting your attempt rather than asking blind question.

Comment: @Raman Shrivastava,please see my edit.

Comment: listEmployeess() - spelling is wrong based upon your method declaration in initial code.
toJson() returns a String. Why are you not storing toJson()'s result in a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign returned json value to `String` object and then pass it to `ModelAndView`. Refer [`Gson.toJson()`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object%29) and also make sure your class(`EmployeeBean`) is `serializable`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView employeelist() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(employeeService.listEmployeess());

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject(json);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: ,Thanks.That helped a lot.